# Why does my div overlap the other div in my code?

Tags: html, css

I have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/z2zgqqzL/), where `a` and `b` div blocks are on left and right side respectively.

```
<!--HTML-->
<div style="background-color:#125467" id="a">a</div>
<div style="background-color:#AABBFF" id="b">b</div>
<div style="background-color:#990033" id="c">c</div>
<div style="background-color:#885544" id="d">d</div>
<div style="background-color:#7799BB" id="e">e</div>
<div style="background-color:#33FF88" id="f">f</div>
<div style="background-color:brown" id="g">g</div>
<div style="background-color:blue" id="h">h</div

/*CSS*/
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
* {
    border: 1px black dashed
}

#a {
    float:left;
}

#b {
    float:right;
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand why `d` block overlaps `c` block like on the following picture:
[image: C block overlapped by d block]

but other blocks go normally. I know that if I add

```
#c {
    clear: both;
}
```

everything will be ok.
[image]

But why without `clear:both` it behaves in such way?

Comment: The whole problem is that floated objects do not add to the height of the object they reside in properly.
https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: why don't u add class for block d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the d block is not overlapping c.
It's the a block that's overlapping c.

This happens because both a and b are `float`'ed and the browsers sees them with a computed height of 0px meaning that c, d, e, f all move up the page, and because a appears first in the DOM it sits on top of c.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the `float: left` property

The default display mode is `block`. So the divs will go right after the other in a new line. But since you have set `float: left` to `#a`.The div is taken from the normal flow ignoring the #a position with respect to other elements and hence it overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try Making The Container

```
Position:relative;
```

and the elements or  inside it

```
Position:absolute;
```